# How does read_input() function work

Tags: c++, function, input

I found this code on the internet and found out it is 3 times faster than `cin` can somebody explain me how it works. Why while loops are needed? thanks!

```
int read_input() {

    int _integer=0;
    char _char=0;

    while(_char<48){
        _char=getchar_unlocked();
    }

    while(_char>=48){
        _integer=10*_integer+_char-48;
        _char=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return _integer; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you edit the code to use character literals rather than numbers it gets a bit clearer:

```
int read_input() {

    int _integer=0;
    char _char=0;

    while(_char<'0'){
        _char=getchar_unlocked();
    }

    while(_char>='0'){
        _integer=10*_integer+_char-'0';
        _char=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return _integer; 
}
```

It discards the characters in the stream until it finds one that is greater than or equal to '0'. It then reads in characters one at a time and multiplies them into an integer result until it finds one that is less than '0'.

Note that this code is possibly quite buggy depending on the input strings it is supposed to accept. For example it would merrily parse "XYZ" as a number.

The reason it is fast is that it is not thread safe, doesn't have any error handling and only handles integers. Generally safer code is slightly slower and more specialised code is faster. `std::stream` is fast enough for most use cases and the safety is more important.

Comment: Thank you so much!